# Missing command-line template

Tags: xcode

I'm following a dated tutorial involving creating command-line code via Xcode.  I remember there was a template to do that; that's now missing in Xcode 10.1.

What would be the alternative?

Comment: Show a screenshot of what the New Project Assistant looks like when you select macOS at the top of the assistant.

Comment: Whoa..... forgot to check macOS.... I was thinking 'cross platform' !

Answer (score 0):

My error: I was checking 'cross-platform' vs macOS:

[image]